# how to authenticate with custom uid in firebase realtime database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

this is my realtime database

[image]

I use firebase realtime database, I use rules as below:

```
 {
  "rules": {
    "$uid": {
    ".read":"$uid === auth.uid",
    ".write": false
  }
}
}
```

when I use the playground rules as below it works, here I managed to read the 121212 data above.

[image]

This is my code snippet.

```
<script>
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import {
        initializeApp
    } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.11/firebase-app.js";
    import {
        getDatabase,
        ref,
        onValue,
    } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.11/firebase-database.js";
    import {
        getAuth,
        signInWithCustomToken,
        createCustomToken
    } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.11/firebase-auth.js";

    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "",
        appId: "",
        measurementId: ""
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

</script>
```

The problem is, I want to read 121212 data via javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`auth.uid`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-authentication) is UID of user logged in with [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth) in your web app requesting the data. First you'll have to sign them in:

```
import {
  getAuth,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.11/firebase-auth.js";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, "user@domain.tld", "password").then((user) => {
  // read data using Firebase Realtime Database SDK
})
```

Firebase has recently posted many tutorials on their YouTube channel that would be useful:

- [Firebase Auth and Firestore - Javascript Crash Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knk5Fjrpde0)
- [Getting Started with the Firebase Realtime Database on the Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pP7quzFmWBY)
- [Getting started with Firebase Authentication on the web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbuSx1yEgV8)

Comment: I want to make my own uid or custom. No login required, so I just provided random characters for the uid.

Comment: @Alex then you should be using [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to create users using a custom UID. Otherwise you cannot pass any custom params to database requests. The login is required if you want to access the `auth` object in security rules. If you dont want to implement auth, checkout [this answer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) for a workaround.

Comment: is this login via gmail?

Comment: @Alex no, first you create a user in Firebase auth with custom UID using Admin SDK. Essentially same as creating using createUserWithEmailAndPassword but it let's you set a custom UID. Then you'll have to log in user with that email.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the user to have to provide credentials, but still want then to only be able to access their own data, consider using Firebase's [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) where signing in is as easy as:

```
import { getAuth, signInAnonymously } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
await signInAnonymously(auth);
```